# Python 3, Trying to login to facebook and get soucecode

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I am trying to log into Facebook by sending post request, and get HTML source code from my profile page.

I have tried many ways, but my script always returns me the same login page.

Hopefully someone can give me some hints/suggestions.

```
import http.cookiejar
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from urllib.request import urlopen


post_data = {
    'email':'xxx',
    'pass':'xxx',
    'legacy_return':'1',
    'trynum':'1',
    'timezone':'240',
    'lgndim':'xxx',
    'lgnrnd':'xxx',
    'lgnjs': 'xxx'
}

try:
    cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_data)
    encode_data = login_data.encode('UTF-8')
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64)')]
    opener.open('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?', encode_data)
    resp = opener.open('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?')
    print (resp.read().decode('utf-8'))
    print (resp.geturl())
except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
    print(err.code)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the Facebook login shows that Facebook POSTs more variables than you have in your code.  I know that FB has been trying to crack down extensively on scraping and my guess is that they are using on-page javascript and other techniques to prevent you from doing what you want to do.

I tried using the plugin "[Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/)" for Firefox to intercept a POST call to /login, I copied every single variable (including ones you don't use like 'lsd' and 'qsstamp'), but simulating the request in Python still doesn't work.

In the end, the simplest answer is to use the Facebook APIs.  Graph API docs are [found here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think there must be a way to achieve this using python library.

Comment: @JunYuZhou you achieved it?